# Is there a way to know the status of a node using the network map service?

Tags: corda

Looking through the documentation I can't find a way to get the current status of the nodes (online/offline) using the *network map service*.

Is this already implemented?
I can find this information using OS tools but I would like to know if there is a Corda way for this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented as of Corda V3. However, you can implement this functionality yourself. For example, see the Ping Pong sample [here](https://github.com/corda/samples) that allows you to ping other nodes.

In the future, it is expected that the network map will regularly poll each node on the network. Nodes that did not respond for a certain period of time (as defined by the network operator) would be evicted from the network map. However, this period of time is expected to be long (e.g. a month).

Please also note that:

- In Corda, communication between nodes uses message acknowledgments. If a node is offline when you send it a message, no acknowledgment will be received, and the node will store the message to disk and retry delivery later. It will continue to retry until the counterparty acknowledges receipt of the message
- Corda is designed with "always-on" nodes in mind. A node being offline will generally correspond to a disaster scenario, and the situation should not be long-lasting

Comment: Added a link to the PingPong CorDapp which replicates this functionality.